# How to echo user post like of Facebook using API

Tags: php, facebook

Hy today I am trying to fetch user status I'd using Facebook API through access token and I am success but when I try to fetch likes on that post then it doesn't echo any data ... I don't know where I do mistake 
**Here is my code**

```
<?
require 'token.php';
require 'uid.php';

$feed=json_decode(file_get_contents('https://graph.fb.me/'.$uid.'/feed?access_token='.$token.'&limit=1'),true);
$idstt = $feed['data'][0]['id'];
$stt = explode("_", $idstt);
$idstt= $stt[1];
$sllike = $feed['data']['0']['likes']['count'];
echo $sllike;
echo $idstt;

?>
```

Here is the output only status I'd
[See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdDYo.jpg)

This is my post I'd but how I echo likes of that post *thanks in advance*

Comment: Do a `var_dump` of your $feed variable, to see what data you actually got there, and in what structure.

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand your question clearly, but I guess like that:

```
$a=1;
$b=2;
$newarr = compact("a","b");
```

if use

```
 print_r($newarr);
```

result is

```
Array ( [a] => 1 [b] => 2 )
```

if use

```
echo json_encode($newarr);
```

result is

```
 {"a":1,"b":2}
```